# PySpark: Absolute value of a column. TypeError: a float is required

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe `df` created as follow,

```
schema = StructType([StructField('Id', StringType(), False),
                     StructField('Value', FloatType(), False)])  
df = spark.createDataFrame([('a',5.0),('b',1.0),('c',-0.3)],schema)
```

It looks like

```
+---+-----+
| Id|Value|
+---+-----+
|  a|  5.0|
|  b|  1.0|
|  c| -0.3|
+---+-----+
```

Now I want to take absolute value of `Value`, which should return

```
+---+-----+
| Id|Value|
+---+-----+
|  a|  5.0|
|  b|  1.0|
|  c|  0.3|
+---+-----+
```

I've tried

```
df = df.withColumn('Value',math.fabs(df.Value))
```

But it complains `TypeError: a float is required.` However Value column was specified with `FloatType()`.

Any clue on how to correctly do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the native `Spark` function `abs()`:

```
from  pyspark.sql.functions import abs

df1 = df.withColumn('Value',abs(df.Value))
df1.show()
+---+-----+
| Id|Value|
+---+-----+
|  a|  5.0|
|  b|  1.0|
|  c|  0.3|
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Great. I've tried this before but without importing abs, and got a TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable, which was a bit misleading for me.  Thanks!

Comment: I think there are better ways to import `abs` without shadowing the python native `abs`. Better ways: `... import abs as abs_` or `from pyspark.sql import functions as F` and then `F.abs()`.